Closed form for $\overset{\infty}{\underset{n=1}{\sum}}\Large \frac{n^s}{n+a}$

Closed form for $\overset{\infty}{\underset{n=1}{\sum}}\Large \frac{n^s}{n+a}$

I have made several attempts, but they all result in failure.$ $
I was originally working on this problem:
$\overset{\infty}{\underset{n=1}{\sum}}  \zeta (n-s)x^n \text{, where $s$ and $x$ are real numbers}$
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\zeta (n-s)x^n\\
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}m^{s-n}x^n\\
=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} m^s\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x}{m}\right)^n\\
=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} m^s\frac{\frac{x}{m}}{1-\frac{x}{m} }\\
=x\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{m^s}{m-x}\\
\end{equation}
And then I don’t know what to do.$ $
I tried to do it by integration:
$$\qquad \text{Li}_s(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n^s}$$
$$\qquad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+a-1}}{n^s}= x^{a-1}\text{Li}_s(x)$$
$$\qquad \int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+a-1}}{n^s}\text{dx}= \int_0^1 x^{a-1}\text{Li}_s(x) \text{dx} $$
$$\qquad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{-s}}{n+a}= \int_0^1 x^{a-1}\text{Li}_s(x) \text{dx} $$
Which is similar to the original problem but I don’t know how to integrate it.$ $
I tried to use Feynman’s trick:
$$I(t)= \int_0^1 x^{a-1}\text{Li}_s(tx) \text{dx}$$
$$I’(t)= \int_0^1 x^{a-1}\frac{1}{t}\text{Li}_{s-1}(tx) \text{dx}$$
After integration by parts and some simplifications:
$$tI’(t)+aI(t)= \text{Li}_{s}(t), I(0)=0$$
Then it returns the original problem.
I have also tried representing $\frac{1}{n+a}$ as $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(n+a)t}\text{dt}$
$$\qquad \sum_{n\geq1}\frac{n^s}{n+a}
= \sum_{n\geq1}n^s\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(n+a)t}\text{dt}$$
$$\qquad = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-at}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{(e^{-t})^n}{n^{-s}} \text{dt}$$
$$= \int_0^{\infty}e^{-at}\text{Li}_{-s}(e^{-t})\text{dt}$$
$$= \int_0^1u^{a-1}\text{Li}_{-s}(u)\text{du, }u=e^{-t}$$
Which I don’t know how to solve.$ $
At least, I have a clue that
$$\qquad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{-a}}{n+s}=
\mathcal{L}_t\{\text{Li}_a(e^{-t})\}(s)$$
I have even got an exotic looking representation for it:
$$\qquad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^s}{n+a}$$
$$\qquad = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\text{D}_t^s\left[\frac{e^{nt}}{n+a}\right] _{t=0}$$
$$\qquad = \text{D}_t^s \left[e^t\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{nt}}{n+a+1}\right] _{t=0} $$
$$= \text{D}_t^s\left[e^t\Phi(e^t,1,a+1)\right] _{t=0} $$
Where D$_t^s$ means the $s$th derivative with respect to $t$. $ $
And $\Phi$ represent the Lerch transcendent.
Edits
I have studied a special case where $s=-k$ for some positive integer k:
$$\qquad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^k(n-a)}
=\frac{-1}{a^k} \left(\psi(1-a)+\gamma+\frac{1}{a}\sum_{n=2}^ka^n\zeta(n) \right) $$
Here is the proof:
$$\text{Set } \frac{1}{n^k(n-a)}
=\frac{c_0}{n^k}+ \frac{c_1}{n^{k-1}}+… +\frac{c_{k-1}}{n}+\frac{c_k}{n-a}$$
$$1-c_kn^k=(n-a)(c_0+c_1n+…+c_{k-1}n^{k-1})$$
Comparing the coefficients:
$$-ac_0=1\\c_0-ac_1=0\\c_1-ac_2=0\\…\\c_{k-2}-ac_{k-1}=0\\c_{k-1}=-c_n$$
Solving it, we get:
$$\qquad\frac{1}{n^k(n-a)}=\frac{\frac{1}{a^k}}{n-a}+\sum_{r=0}^{k-1}\frac{\frac{-1}{a^{r+1}}}{n^{k-r}}$$
$$\qquad\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^k(n-a)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\frac{1}{a^k}}{n-a}+ \frac{\frac{-1}{a^k}}{n}+\sum_{r=0}^{k-2}\frac{\frac{-1}{a^{r+1}}}{n^{k-r}}\right)$$
$$\qquad=\frac{-1}{a^k}\left(\psi(1-a)+\gamma\right)
-\frac{1}{a}\sum_{r=0}^{k-2}\frac{\zeta(k-r)}{a^r}$$
Substitute $n=k-r$:
$$\qquad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^k(n-a)}
=\frac{-1}{a^k} \left(\psi(1-a)+\gamma+\frac{1}{a}\sum_{n=2}^ka^n\zeta(n) \right) $$
So my question is:
Are there any closed form for $\overset{\infty}{\underset{n=1}{\sum}}\Large \frac{n^s}{n+a}$ where $s<0$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ ?
Any hints or answers would be very helpful! I’m very interested in this beautiful summation now.

What kind of number is $a$ and what is $s$ ?

You could try and represent the summand as an integral and swap order of summation and integration.
$\int_0^\infty e^{-(n+a)t}dt = \frac{1}{n+a}$

The continuous case is very interesting. The problem is that Euler-MacLaurin summation leads to a monster.

@user1164922 It doesn’t quite work. Thanks for advice though. Any advice might be helpful!

why do you think such a representation exists?

The second line of your computation requires that $n-s>1$

I don’t mind if you arbitrarily put some restrictions on $a$ and $s$, I just want a solution.

If $s$ is a negative integer and $a>0$, the pattern is very interesting

Here is a sample for Claude's commnt, $s=-5$, courtesy of Maple...$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {1}{{n}^{5} \left( n+a \right) }}={\frac {
\gamma}{{a}^{5}}}-{\frac {\zeta \left( 2 \right) }{{a}^{4}}}+{\frac {
\zeta \left( 3 \right) }{{a}^{3}}}-{\frac {\zeta \left( 4 \right) }{{a
}^{2}}}+{\frac {\zeta \left( 5 \right) }{a}}+{\frac {\Psi \left( 1+a
\right) }{{a}^{5}}}$$  Here $\Psi$ is the digamma function. and $\gamma$ is Euler-Mascheroni

I would go the other way, namely the trapezoidal rule:
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\approx \frac{f(a)}{2}+\frac{f(b)}{2}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}f(a+k) $$
where $a+n=b$
After few transformations we can write:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}f(a+k)\approx\int_{a-\frac{1}{2}}^{b+\frac{1}{2}}f(x)dx  $$
Or taking into account given problem:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)\approx\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\infty}f(x)dx  $$
Therefore:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^s}{n+a}\approx\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\infty}\frac{x^s}{x+a}dx$$
$s$ must of course be such that both the sum and the integral converge.
As an example let's take $s=-1 ; a=1$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=1$$
$$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x(x+1)}dx=\ln 3 =1.09861$$
If you want a more accurate approximation, you should consider more accurate numerical algorithms.

Taking the approximation as $$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{x^s}{x+a-\frac{1}{2}}\text{dx}$$will make the results much more accurate. In fact, I asked this question because I thought there must be someone who defined a special function for it.
